# Does the address of the result of std::string::operator[] point to a writable, nul-terminated buffer?

Tags: c++, stl, operators, stdstring, c++03

I am modifying a function that accepts a const char* and uses a function, ProcessString.  ProcessString is a function that expects a null-terminated character buffer as a char*.  The characters in the buffer may or may not be modified, as defined by the function signature below.  To "bridge the gap", I am using a temporary std::string:

```
void ProcessString( char* str );

void SomeFunction( const char* str )
{
  string temp(str);
  ProcessString( &temp[0] );
}
```

My primary question is about the guarantees of std::string::operator[] and whether the address returned by the &temp[0] above is a usable, null-terminated buffer as a char*.  Secondly, and very much secondly, is there a better way to do this?

I am using C++03.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only has well-defined behavior in C++11; in previous standards, `std::string` did not guarantee contiguous storage for its internal buffer.

However while that code is completely fine in C++11, the more idiomatic approach is to use `std:vector<char>`, which has guaranteed contiguous storage since C++03:

```
void ProcessString(char* str);

void SomeFunction(char const* str)
{
    // + 1 for terminating NUL
    std::vector<char> temp(str, str + std::strlen(str) + 1);
    ProcessString(&temp[0]); // or temp.data() in C++11
}
```

Comment: If `str` is not NULL, then you could use `strlen()+1` and avoid the `push_back()`.

Comment: I'm all but certain that C++11 does guarantee that the string contained in the buffer is null-terminated.  `c_str` returns "A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`" and requires that "the program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array."

Comment: @James: `c_str` is allowed to add the NUL, until `c_str` is called there's no requirement that one exist.  "the program shall not alter" is a restriction on what the user can do with the resultant pointer (e.g. no `const_cast` and then modification), not a restriction on `c_str` implementators.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Oops, I misread "the program shall not" as "the implementation shall not."  Thanks.  Anyway, I think the best solution is to call `c_str()`, then use `&s[0]`.

Comment: @Remy: It doesn't seem like `NULL` is a legal input to `strlen` to begin with.

Comment: @Ben, C++11 promises that `operator[](size())` is a reference to a nul character, irrespective of `c_str`. However, I don't see the requirement that `&operator[](size())` immediately follows `&operator[](size()-1)`, except in the description of `c_str`.

Comment: I've seen a lot of "solutions" to my problem, including this answer, but this is the only answer so far to address my real question.  From what I gather, operator[] only returns a reference to a char, period; no guarantees about contiguous memory, etc.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Kaiged : In C++11, both `std::basic_string<>` and `std::vector<>` are guaranteed to have contiguous storage. In C++03, only `std::vector<>` had that guarantee. In C++98, neither had that guarantee. The question is which standard the compiler you're using is adhering to.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that's why I said: "if str is not NULL ..."

Comment: @Remy: ... and if `str` is `NULL`, then the code was already broken, so changing it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thank you for clarifying.  I should have specified that our compiler uses C++03.  Too bad we won't be updating to C++11 for a while.

Comment: @RobKennedy:  Thanks for that comment.  I was sure that requirement was in there somewhere, I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small class to face this kind of problem, I have implemented the RAII idiom.

```
class DeepString
{
        DeepString(const DeepString& other);
        DeepString& operator=(const DeepString& other);
        char* internal_; 

    public:
        explicit DeepString( const string& toCopy): 
            internal_(new char[toCopy.size()+1]) 
        {
            strcpy(internal_,toCopy.c_str());
        }
        ~DeepString() { delete[] internal_; }
        char* str() const { return internal_; }
        const char* c_str()  const { return internal_; }
};
```

And you can use it as:

```
void aFunctionAPI(char* input);

//  other stuff

aFunctionAPI("Foo"); //this call is not safe. if the function modified the 
                     //literal string the program will crash
std::string myFoo("Foo");
aFunctionAPI(myFoo.c_str()); //this is not compiling
aFunctionAPI(const_cast<char*>(myFoo.c_str())); //this is not safe std::string 
                                                //implement reference counting and 
                                                //it may change the value of other
                                                //strings as well.
DeepString myDeepFoo(myFoo);
aFunctionAPI(myFoo.str()); //this is fine
```

I have called the class DeepString because it is creating a deep and unique copy (the DeepString is not copyable) of an existing string.

Comment: I don't think that I'll use this to solve my problem, but I like seeing how others solve problems with utility classes such as this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go from a `const char*` to a `char *`, why not use [strdup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx), and then free the buffer when ProcessString is done?

Going through `std::string` seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Using a std::string does exactly that.

Comment: I definitely need some sort of temporary buffer that only lives in the scope of SomeFunction.  I like this idea and using std::vector by ildjarn, above.

Comment: `strdup` is not ISO and requires explicit `free` + exception handling.